# NSOutlineView Fault

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsoutlineview

In my Application I have a NSOutlineview which is getting refresh too frequently, and crashing , getting following stack trace

```
Exception Name: NSInternalInconsistencyException
Description: (null) should not be expanded already!
User Info: (null)

0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff918840a6 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff96eef3f0 objc_exception_throw + 43
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff91883ee8 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 104
3   Foundation                          0x00007fff9769a6a2 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 189
4   AppKit                              0x00007fff933e19b0 -[NSOutlineView _expandItemEntry:expandChildren:startLevel:] + 1153
5   AppKit                              0x00007fff933c7c42 -[NSOutlineView _uncachedNumberOfRows] + 379
6   AppKit                              0x00007fff93401938 -[NSOutlineView frameOfCellAtColumn:row:] + 66
7   AppKit                              0x00007fff9379f51c -[NSTableViewDynamicToolTipManager dynamicToolTipRectAtPoint:] + 298
8   AppKit                              0x00007fff9385cb9a -[NSViewDynamicToolTipManager _markMovementTrackingInfo] + 142
9   AppKit                              0x00007fff933f5d0a -[NSViewDynamicToolTipManager _restartMovementTracking] + 231
10  AppKit                              0x00007fff933f5b8b -[NSViewDynamicToolTipManager _viewVisibleBoundsChanged] + 526
11  AppKit                              0x00007fff933f58eb -[NSViewDynamicToolTipManager _threadsafeViewVisibleBoundsChanged] + 39
12  AppKit                              0x00007fff9336cda7 -[NSView(NSInternal) _updateTrackingAreas] + 479
13  AppKit                              0x00007fff933f6be8 -[NSOutlineView _updateTrackingAreas] + 99
14  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9187ca46 __NSArrayEnumerate + 582
15  AppKit                              0x00007fff9336d090 -[NSView(NSInternal) _updateTrackingAreas] + 1224
16  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9187ca46 __NSArrayEnumerate + 582
17  AppKit                              0x00007fff9336d090 -[NSView(NSInternal) _updateTrackingAreas] + 1224
18  AppKit                              0x00007fff9336dded -[NSScrollView _updateTrackingAreas] + 122
19  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9187ca46 __NSArrayEnumerate + 582
20  AppKit                              0x00007fff9336d090 -[NSView(NSInternal) _updateTrackingAreas] + 1224
21  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9187ca46 __NSArrayEnumerate + 582
22  AppKit                              0x00007fff9336d090 -[NSView(NSInternal) _updateTrackingAreas] + 1224
23  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9187ca46 __NSArrayEnumerate + 582
24  AppKit                              0x00007fff9336d090 -[NSView(NSInternal) _updateTrackingAreas] + 1224
25  AppKit                              0x00007fff9336caac _handleInvalidCursorRectsNote + 863
26  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9184a9b7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
27  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9184a921 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 369
28  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff91825d88 __CFRunLoopRun + 728
29  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff918256b2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 290
30  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff96a0f0a4 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 209
31  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff96a0ee42 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 356
32  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff96a0ecd3 BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 62
33  AppKit                              0x00007fff93292613 _DPSNextEvent + 685
34  AppKit                              0x00007fff93291ed2 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 128
35  AppKit                              0x00007fff93289283 -[NSApplication run] + 517
36  AppKit                              0x00007fff9322dcb6 NSApplicationMain + 869
```

This is the Assertion i am getting,

```
*** Assertion failure in -[MyCustomOutlineView _expandItemEntry:expandChildren:startLevel:], /SourceCache/AppKit/AppKit-1187.34/TableView.subproj/NSOutlineView.m:1309
2013-01-16 21:16:41.346 AppName[4149:303] (null) should not be expanded already!
```

Any clue how can i debug it

**Editing the Scenario**

this is Client -- Server Application,

```
Client will listen from a Socket in a **thread, and data will come in XML Format**
In the same thread it will Extract the XML Data and Form a NSMutableDictionary & NSMutableArray 

something like this, 

NSMutableArray  *rootArray = will contain all first level of item, 

each element of rootArray will be of type OutlineViewData class, this will contain any additional info whether they are single element or it can be another group item , 

if at all they are group item again there will be an array and so on.. 

**From listen thread i am calling OutlineView reload data over main thread.**
```

**What i am suspecting**

This is how its happening,

```
void SocketListenerThread(){

    while ( hasData ){
        if ( xmlOutLineData ){
          pData = Make Outline Data ; // This is modifying the Data which will be  
                                      // display/used by the NSOutlineView 

        }

       [ Call To Reload the NSOutlineView on the main thread ]
    }
}
```

I was expecting NSOutlineView reloadData is blocking call, but it seems its not blocking call, this is might be happing, i am editing / may be deleting or adding some entry to pData which is again being refered by NSOutline delegate Method to display Outlineview,

**Are there any way to have blockingBehavior of NSOutlineView reloadData** 
Thanks in Advance..

Comment: You've posted the stack trace and the error message. Great! Now please post the code you use to interface with the outline view.

Comment: you mean Interface within my code that i am using to process the NSOutlineView or NSOutlineView interface...?

Comment: Our crystal ball is broken, so we can't determine what's causing this crash. Your subject line implies it's the outline view's fault yet this control is used by thousands of apps ... it's more likely you've got an error somewhere. So: post the details of your outline-view-related code. If you're using bindings, describe them very thoroughly.

Comment: @JoshuaNozzi : I understand, i just tried to explain the logic the way i am using NSOutlineView, it seems i was expecting NSOutlineView reloadData is blocking call, but it wasn't i just check with the log.

Comment: What *is* the call to reload the outline view on the main thread? You really should be posting as much detail as possible - this is like pulling teeth right now.

Answer (score -1):

`reloadData` only sets a flag in the NSOutlineView to trigger calls to your data source.
Your code is basically i busy loop, that will never return to the main `runLoop` to actually process any state changes to the GUI (or the NSOutlineView instance itself).

What you should do is to create your data on a separate thread and call a refresh function on the main thread.

You are now calling non-threadsafe code on a different thread than the main thread.

Use something like:
`[myController performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(refreshOutlineView:) withObject:myDataArray waitUntilDone:YES];`

`refreshOutlineView` should add the newly ceated data to an array or whatever underlying objects you use in your datasource.

`myDataArray` contains the data records you created.

Afterwards call `reloadData` within that method.